# How can i add all elements in html with Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

```
File input = new File("1727209867.htm");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8","http://www.facebook.com/people/Alison-Vella/1727209867");
```

I am trying to parse this html file which is saved and using in local system. But parsing dont parse all html. So i cant reach information that i need. Parse only work for 6k char with this code but actually html file has 60k char.

Comment: I don't think there is such a low limit for input. I worked with larger input (in other constellations). There must be some different go wrong

Comment: How do you determine this 6k limit?

Comment: i check doc(Document doc) and it has only 6k char and didnt finish

Comment: So interesting but i am normally using eclipse indigo for writing java. But i tried same code in NetBeans at Maven project it worked.

Comment: Jsoup cant handle this, but its possible with a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in jsoup, but with a **workaround**:

```
final File input = new File("example.html");
final int maxLength = 6000; // Limit of char's to read

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(input); // Open file for reading
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(maxLength); // Init the "buffer" with the size required
int count = 0; // Count of chars readen
int c; // Char for reading

while( ( c = is.read() ) != -1 && count < maxLength ) // Read a single char until limit is reached
{
    sb.append((char) c); // Save the char into the buffer
    count++; // increment the chars readen
}


Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString()); // Parse the Html from buffer
```

**Explained:**

1. Read the file *char-by-char* into a buffer until you reach the limit
2. Parse the text from buffer and process it with jsoup

**Problem:** This wont take care about closing tags etc - it will stop reading exactly if you are on the limit.

***(Possible)*** Solutions:

- ignore this and stop exactly where you are, parse this and "*fix*" or drop the hanging html
- if you are at the end, read until you reach next closing tag or `>` char
- if you are at the end, read until you reach next block-tag
- if you are at the end, read until a specific tag or comment